# How to set ordering settings for YouTube playlist

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Ordering is no longer available natively:

[image]

After the new UI update, YouTube has following as the option:

[image]

Is there a way I can set ordering as *manual*?

Comment: Unfortunately, currently there's no API endpoint that would allow you to set the behavior you need. But have you tried tweaking the setting *Add new videos to top of playlist*?

Comment: Current interface (without API) allows 5 kind of sorts and also manual positioning. With the API there is [PlaylistItems: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert) and [PlaylistItems: update](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/update) which support positioning according to the documentation.